# How to get value of corresponding cell of table on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on HTML table on click using react I have a HTML table on which one one part is clickable , I want to capture Id on click of name of that particular row and then open new route and pass that value and use it to other route which is open.

But here I am struggling to get the corresponding value

I made name clickable and want to get that particular row Id of that name and then pass that

My Code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const App = () => {
  //const history = useHistory();
  const data = [
    {
      name: "mark",
      age: 25,
      gender: "Female",
      working: "No"
    },
    {
      name: "steve",
      age: 36,
      gender: "Male",
      working: "Yes"
    }
  ];
  const clickEvt = () => {
    alert("clickerd"); //here I want the age gender of clicked row
    //history.push("/employee_profile"); here I want to pass the data
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="table-responsive">
        <table className="table table-bordered">
          <thead className="table-secondary">
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Gender</th>
              <th>Working</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {data.map(item => (
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <a onClick={clickEvt} className="linkValue">
                    {item.name}
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td>{item.age}</td>
                <td>{item.gender}</td>
                <td>{item.working}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[codesand box link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-buck-83t6g?file=/src/App.js:0-1401)

Answer (score 2):

```
  <a onClick={()=> clickEvt(item)} className="linkValue">
                    {item.name}
  </a>
```

Then, You can use the variable inside clickevnt by

```
 const clickEvt = (person) => {
    console.log('Got the age::',person.age);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass `item` through to your callback like...

```
 <a onClick={(e) => clickEvt(e, item)} className="linkValue">
```

As for passing data through to the new route, you can have a global state using reacts built-in context API or redux.

Then, set the selected profile in your global state before redirecting, and retrieve from global state once in the employee_profile route.